# More terse way to filter Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

The following code works.

```
df1 =  df.loc[lambda df: df.myfield == 'abc' , ['myfield' ,  'field2', 'field3','field4']]
print df1.iloc[:60]
```

However I would just like to print out the selected columns of the first 60 entries of df matching my 'abc' condition in a single statement without this extra step of assigning to df1 then doing the 2nd iloc statement. I tried adding a 2nd condition in my lambda but could not get it to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can simply dispense with the lambda and just use `df.myfield == 'abc'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, you should be able to simplify this to:

```
print df.loc[df.myfield == 'abc', ['myfield', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']].iloc[:60]
```

generally, I would do something like:

```
row_selection = df.myfield == 'abc'
col_selection = ['myfield', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
print df.loc[row_selection, col_selection].iloc[:60]
```